# Django value too long for type character varying(50)

Tags: python, django, overriding

I am trying to create a Site object.

```
http://test-ecommerce-project-dev.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

And when I try to create a new Site with the above domain, I got this error

```
value too long for type character varying(50)
```

i think this is caused because my domain is too long. But I don't know how to solve it.

I thought of overriding Site class, but i don't know how to do it either.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating this Site? The name field has a limit of 50 chars but is meant to be a human-readable name and can be shorter rather than a repeat of the domain

Comment: my name of this Site is same as the domain. Should I change it?

Comment: Yeah, try changing the name to just the subdomain "test-ecommerce-project-dev" or something human-readable like "DEV"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From lain Shelvington's comment i realized that my name was too long.
So I shortened the name to "test-ecommerce-dev".